# Linking dygraphs.js to d3 charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, dygraphs

I'm currently working on building a charting web application, and I've chosen dygraphs for my time series data (Two weeks of data at an hourly level, if anyone finds this information relevant). On the same page, I also have a couple of customized d3.js charts that pull metrics from the same database as the trendline.

I want to know if I will be able to link the selection on my dygraph line (Supposing I zoom in on 3 hours worth of data, i.e., 3 rows) - to my d3 charts, so that the data in the d3 charts also get filtered down to the date range chosen by zooming in?

I'm quite the amateur here, and apologize if my question seems vague, but any sense of direction would be helpful.
I'm guessing I should be able to do this by modifying some class in the dygraphs source code, or reference the same from my d3 chart.

Thanks.

Comment: You could do this by having a global "range" that is set when the dygraphs selection changes and used by the D3 graphs.

Comment: Interesting. I was just going through the Dygraphs API reference, and it mentions an xAxisRange() class that returns the date range selection. I'm thinking I should be able to use this to create a global  range as you suggested, and go ahead. Will post code, if I have some progress.

Comment: An exercise in pointlessness. I learnt I have no idea on how to call said method (xAxisRange()), to even display the selected range. Any clue on how I can do this?

Comment: You can call this on the dygraphs object you've created for the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have any trouble doing this. There's no need to modify the dygraphs source. You can implement handlers on the dygraph object (`zoomHandler` or `drawCallback`, most likely) which update the D3 chart.

See [this demo](http://dygraphs.com/tests/synchronize.html) for an example of synchronization between multiple dygraphs.